# Jython - Unable to Install 'ensurepip'

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython, jython-2.7

I am trying to install packages to a Jython install and so far I'm unsuccessful.

The install of Jython is at this location on my machine. [Note paths have been truncated manually - '..']

```
"F:\Programs\..\docs\javacommon\jython.jar"
```

There is an existing, empty Library location at this same location:

```
"F:\Programs\..\docs\javacommon\Lib"
```

When I try to run the following to install ensurepip:

```
java -jar jython.jar -m ensurepip
```

This however fails with the following error:

```
 Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
Cleaning up...
[31mException:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9j_zno\pip-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\basecommand.py", line 133, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9j_zno\pip-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\commands\install.py", line 325, in run
    requirement_set.install(
  File "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9j_zno\pip-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\commands\install.py", line 325, in run
    requirement_set.install(
  File "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9j_zno\pip-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\req\req_set.py", line 633, in install
    requirement.install(
  File "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9j_zno\pip-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\req\req_install.py", line 719, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9j_zno\pip-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\req\req_install.py", line 990, in move_wheel_files
    move_wheel_files(
  File "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9j_zno\pip-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\wheel.py", line 133, in move_wheel_files
    scheme = distutils_scheme(name, user=user, home=home, root=root)
  File "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9j_zno\pip-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\locations.py", line 178, in distutils_scheme
    i.finalize_options()
  File "F:\Programs\..\javacommon\jython.jar\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 386, in finalize_options
    self.set_undefined_options('build',
  File "F:\Programs\..\javacommon\jython.jar\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 298, in set_undefined_options
    src_cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "F:\Programs\..\javacommon\jython.jar\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "F:\Programs\..\javacommon\jython.jar\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 118, in finalize_options
    self.executable = os.path.normpath(sys.executable)
  File "F:\Programs\..\javacommon\jython.jar\Lib\ntpath.py", line 402, in normpath
    if path.startswith(('\\\\.\\', '\\\\?\\')):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

What initially looks suspicious here are the install paths and their inclusion of the '.jar' in the path:

```
"F:\Programs\..\javacommon\jython.jar\Lib\ntpath.py"
```

I had a look at the 'sys.path' to see what is on it:

```
['', 'F:\\Programs\\..\\javacommon\\Lib', 'F:\\Programs\\..\\javacommon\\jython.jar\\Lib', '__classpath__', '__pyclasspath__/']
```

I have removed everything from the path barring 'F:\Programs\..\javacommon\Lib' to test the install again but upon restarting Jython the sys.path is automatically reset tot the above.

Any ideas how I can progress? At current I'm trying to get it to install the libraries at the correct folder path so that I can proceed.

To note my end goal is to install the following for my Jython install:

```
python -m pip install numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

Many Thanks in Advance,

Comment: numpy and scipy don't work with Jython: https://scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#id23

Comment: To clarify: even if you get pip/ensurepip working, you will still not be able to use NumPy and SciPy. And Pandas depends on NumPy: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#dependencies.