# Unable to execute -m ensurepip with Jython Jar

Tags: jython, ensurepip

I am unable to execute the following command"

`java -jar ~/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar -m ensurepip`

I get the following stack trace. Can anyone please guide me as to what is the issue and how to solve it?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/***/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/runpy.py", line 161, in _run_module_as_main
  File "/Users/***/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
  File "/Users/***/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/Users/***/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 220, in _main
  File "/Users/***/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 123, in bootstrap
  File "/Users/***/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 45, in _run_pip
  File "/var/folders/96/llwnx0n57vd17gtfyw124z500000gq/T/tmpARwn47/pip-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "/var/folders/96/llwnx0n57vd17gtfyw124z500000gq/T/tmpARwn47/pip-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/util.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "/var/folders/96/llwnx0n57vd17gtfyw124z500000gq/T/tmpARwn47/pip-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/backwardcompat/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
  File "/Users/***/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "/Users/***/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/posixpath.py", line 367, in realpath
  File "/Users/***/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/posixpath.py", line 373, in _joinrealpath
  File "/Users/***/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/posixpath.py", line 61, in isabs
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Thanks and regards, 
Paddy

Tried searching for this specific error and got [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284551/jython-unable-to-install-ensurepip) as first search result but it didn't really helpe me.

**Solution:** Courtesy a github user, I got the solution from Jython github forum, please upgrade your Jython jar to 2.7.3 version and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Courtesy of a GitHub user, I got the solution from the [Jython GitHub forum](https://github.com/jython/jython/issues/315), please upgrade your Jython jar to 2.7.3 version and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [this old post](https://bugs.jython.org/issue1069) where Jython fails to populate the Python executable file name, causing it to be None. If `ensurepip` passes that to `path.abs`, you'll get the error you see here.

If that's your case, you might be able to fix it by passing the value as a `-Dpython.executable` variable to Java itself:

```
java -Dpython.executable="~/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar" -jar ~/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar -m ensurepip
```

Comment: Should I install Jython separately? I thought the standalone JAR itself had a Jython built-in, anyway even after installing Jython separately, I got the same error.  I also tried the aforementioned command with the -Dpython.executable error but I still get the same issue unfortunately.